# How canvas make responsive using pathData method in paperJs?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg, paperjs

**Method A:-** I have imported a `SVG` object in a document, when we re-size window the `SVG` will re-size respectively [[Check the demo]](https://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/n3xa90tf/).

**Method B:-** But the same object I have imported as pathData method in paperJs and re-size the window the canvas object not re-size same as in **Method A** [[Check demo]](https://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/kh9z1eL8/).

I have given the canvas size is full width of the window using by css but in the canvas object couldn't apply responsive.

```
canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
```

What should I do to make the canvas object as responsive? Helping would be appreciated , Thanks in Advance.

Comment: add a `resize` attribute to your canvas element - there's many postings for this on the paper.js forums

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides sorry question is edited. Not only for the canvas, actually how its possible in pathData method (imported svg ) ?

Comment: check for `view.bounds` size and scale your path accordingly when resizing the window.

Comment: Could you make an example fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution.

I have used their own option [fitBounds](http://paperjs.org/reference/group/#fitbounds-rectangle), it's one of the best option that I loved in paperJs. And I have share my another solution too here. I hope may be it will be help you :) .

**Solution 1 :** Using with fitBounds option

```
window.addEventListener("resize", myFunction);
myFunction();

function myFunction() {    
    path.fitBounds(view.bounds);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/kh9z1eL8/2/)

**Solution 2 :** Using with size calculation

```
window.addEventListener("resize", myFunction);
myFunction();

function myFunction() {    
    redrawCanvas();
}

function redrawCanvas(){

    var linePropWidth = view.bounds.width, //2000 is actual width proportion
        lineProHeight = linePropWidth / 6.5; //100 is actual height proportion

    path.strokeWidth = lineProHeight/40; //dynamic stroke size

    path.bounds.width = linePropWidth;
    path.bounds.height = lineProHeight;
    path.bounds.x = view.bounds.x;
    path.bounds.y = view.bounds.y + lineProHeight*2;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/kh9z1eL8/4/)**